# Does this belong?

Tags: discussion

Does [This Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/343260/unknown-issues-installing-jdk) belong here? Looks more like a Super User question to me... (I'm still hesitant to "flag" stuff on the fly, until I know, fur sure that I know my way around these parts and that people like me)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want propose a migration, you've got two options:

1. Flag it and hope for the best (that's totally acceptable)
2. Pop over into the chat room [Vote to Close](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/161/server-fault-vote-to-close) and pop a link to the question in there

Don't worry, we like you until you prove otherwise, so flag away!

Oh, and you have a santa hat, so that's already made you 10x more likable than the default like setting.

Oh yeah, one more thing I should point out, you have a seperate "rep" for flagging (called Flag Weight, look out for it in your profile). This is what affects the "weight" of your flag (well, how high it appears on the todo list anyway) and is seperate from your regular rep (which measures how knowledgable you are). So even if you have 1 rep, you can have a very heavy flag weight.

<sub>Am I the only one who finds it funny that the heavier your flag weight, the higher up the flag queue you go? Anyone who has done year 7 science knows that the heavier you are, the lower you sink, so really it's an inverse flag weight, that makes you lighter. And that's my 2c for the day</sub>

Comment: There is a third option, which might be the best one if you have doubts - Leave it alone and those with voting rights will probably take care of it.

Comment: Ho ho ho, sounds good. Glad my Santa hat helps. Thanks! (I suppose I should say "hoho" instead of "hehe" since I've got my Santa hat on)

Comment: It should be Flag Priority, not Weight... Leave it to programmers to mix them up.

Comment: @Chris, they're probably confusing it with "flag wait", which is used to get even with annoying customers and bosses.